# Is there a way to improve hack speed?

Tags: planetside-2

I spend most of my time as an infiltrator, and one of my favorite activities is to run around hacking every terminal and turret in sight. The slowish rate at which such things are hacked can cause problems however, as enemy troops can catch you uncloaked.

Is there any way to improve an infiltrator's hack speed, much as one might for a medic's rate of healing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is addressed on the PlanetSide 2 [Wiki](http://planetside.wikia.com/wiki/Hacking):

> All infiltrators are able to hack, and the speed can be increased through certing into the Advanced Equipment Terminal Hacking tree.